# Endpoint Paths for APIs inside Docker and Kubernetes

Tags: api, docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I am newbie on Docker and Kubernetes. And now I am developing Restful APIs which later be deployed to Docker containers in a Kubernetes cluster.

How the path of the endpoints will be changed? I have heard that Docker-Swarm and Kubernetes add some ords on the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The "path" part of the endpoint URLs themselves (for this SO question, the `/questions/53008947/...` part) won't change.  But the rest of the URL might.

Docker publishes services at a TCP-port level (`docker run -p` option, Docker Compose `ports:` section) and doesn't look at what traffic is going over a port.  If you have something like an Apache or nginx proxy as part of your stack that might change the HTTP-level path mappings, but you'd probably be aware of that in your environment.

Kubernetes works similarly, but there are more layers.  A container runs in a Pod, and can publish some port out of the Pod.  That's not used directly; instead, a Service refers to the Pod (by its labels) and republishes its ports, possibly on different port numbers.  The Service has a DNS name `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local` that can be used within the cluster; you can also configure the Service to be reachable on a fixed TCP port on every node in the service (`NodePort`) or, if your Kubernetes is running on a public-cloud provider, to create a load balancer there (`LoadBalancer`).  Again, all of this is strictly at the TCP level and doesn't affect HTTP paths.

There is one other Kubernetes piece, an Ingress controller, which acts as a declarative wrapper around the nginx proxy (or something else with similar functionality).  That *does* operate at the HTTP level and could change paths.

The other corollary to this is that the URL to reach a service might be different in different environments: `http://localhost:12345/path` in a local development setup, `http://other_service:8080/path` in Docker Compose, `http://other-service/path` in Kubernetes, `https://api.example.com/other/path` in production.  You need some way to make that configurable (often an environment variable).